# Plotting Multiple Realizations of a Stochastic Process in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, histogram

I'm trying to plot the time evolution graph for Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process, which is a stochastic process, and then find the probability distribution at each time steps. I'm able to plot the graph for `1000` realizations of the process. Each realization has a `1000` time step, with width of the time step as `.001`. I used a `1000 x 1000` array to store the data. Each rows hold value of each realizations. And column wise `i-th` columns correspond value at `i-th` time step for `1000` realizations.

Now I want `bin` results at each time steps together and then plot the probability distribution corresponding to each time step. I'm quite confused with doing it ([I tried modifying code from  IPython Cookbook, where they don't store each realizations in the memory](https://ipython-books.github.io/134-simulating-a-stochastic-differential-equation/)).

The code that I made from the IPython Cookbook:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 1.  # Standard deviation.
mu = 10.  # Mean.
tau = .05  # Time constant.

dt = .001  # Time step.
T = 1.  # Total time.
n = int(T / dt)  # Number of time steps.
ntrails = 1000 # Number of Realizations.
t = np.linspace(0., T, n)  # Vector of times.

sigmabis = sigma * np.sqrt(2. / tau)
sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

x = np.zeros((ntrails,n))  # Vector containing all successive values of our process

for j in range (ntrails):  # Euler Method
    for i in range(n - 1):     
        x[j,i + 1] = x[j,i] + dt * (-(x[j,i] - mu) / tau) + sigmabis * sqrtdt * np.random.randn()

for k in range(ntrails): #plotting 1000 realizations
    plt.plot(t, x[k])

# Time averaging of each time stamp using bin 

# Really lost from this point onwrds.
bins = np.linspace(-2., 15., 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 4))
for i in range(ntrails):
    hist, _ = np.histogram(x[:,[i]], bins=bins)
    ax.plot(hist)
```

Graph for 1000 realizations of Ornstein- Uhlenbeck Process:

[image]

Distribution generated from the code above:

[image]

I'm really lost with assigning of the `bin` value and plotting the histogram using it. I want to know whether my code is correct for plotting distributions corresponding to each time step, using `bin`. If not please tell me what modifications I need to make to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last for loop should iterate over `n`, not `ntrails` (which happen to be the same value here) but otherwise the code and plots look correct (apart from a few minor issues such as that is takes 101 breaks to get 100 bins so your code should probably read `bins = np.linspace(-2., 15., 101)`).

Your plots could be improved a bit though. A good guiding principle is to use as little ink as necessary to communicate the point that you are trying to make. You are always trying to plot *all* the data, which ends up obscuring your plots. Also, you could benefit from paying more attention to colour. Colour should carry meaning, or not be used at all.

Here would be my suggestions:

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.top'] = False
mpl.rcParams['axes.spines.right'] = False

sigma = 1.  # Standard deviation.
mu = 10.  # Mean.
tau = .05  # Time constant.

dt = .001  # Time step.
T = 1  # Total time.
n = int(T / dt)  # Number of time steps.
ntrails = 10000 # Number of Realizations.
t = np.linspace(0., T, n)  # Vector of times.

sigmabis = sigma * np.sqrt(2. / tau)
sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

x = np.zeros((ntrails,n))  # Vector containing all successive values of our process

for j in range(ntrails):  # Euler Method
    for i in range(n - 1):
        x[j,i + 1] = x[j,i] + dt * (-(x[j,i] - mu) / tau) + sigmabis * sqrtdt * np.random.randn()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k in range(200): # plotting fewer realizations shows the distribution better in this case
    ax.plot(t, x[k], color='k', alpha=0.02)

# Really lost from this point onwards.
bins = np.linspace(-2., 15., 101) # you need 101 breaks to get 100 bins
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 4))
# plotting a smaller selection of time points spaced out using a log scale prevents
# the asymptotic approach to the mean from dominating the plot
for i in np.logspace(0, np.log10(n)-1, 21):
    hist, _ = np.histogram(x[:,[int(i)]], bins=bins)
    ax.plot(hist, color=plt.cm.plasma(i/20))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello Paul, so my code is correct, other than the little improvement you added to enhance the output plots? Also if you could please explain what would be the optimal bin value for the current plot?

Comment: Yes, the code is correct apart from the nitpicks I mentioned in my answer. There is no objective criterion to determine an optimal bin size (at least not in an unsupervised setting such as yours). The only way is to plot the results and see if the plot communicates the process that you want it to communicate.